# Player movement script based on a given symmetry

Tags: unity, movement, single-player

I'm trying to make a game where the movement of the second player is based on the first player's movement but with a given line of symmetry. For example, if the inputted symmetry was y=x, then when player 1 moves to the left, player 2 moves down. Problem is, I'm a novice and don't know how to do that. Can someone help me figure out what I need to change in my script to achieve this?

````
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 
 public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
 {
     // Start is called before the first frame update
     
     public float moveSpeed = 5f;
 
     public Rigidbody2D rb; 
     public Animator animator;
 
     Vector2 movement;
 
     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
         movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");   
         movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");   
 
         animator.SetFloat("Horizontal", movement.x);
         animator.SetFloat("Vertical", movement.y);
         animator.SetFloat("Speed", movement.sqrMagnitude);
     }
 
     void FixedUpdate()
     {
         rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
     }
 }
```
````

Comment: Are you just looking for [Vector2.Reflect](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Reflect.html)?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

First define an axis of symmetry. Defining an axis(or a line) in space requires two arguments: the direction(or slope) of the line, and a point that this line passes through.

Then find the symmetry point of a point by Reflect.

[image]

Code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 symmetryPoint = Vector3.zero;
    public Vector3 symmetryAxis = new Vector3(1, 0, 1);
    public GameObject player1;
    public GameObject player2;
    void Update()
    {
        var v1 = symmetryPoint - player1.transform.position;
        var v2 = Vector3.Reflect(v1, symmetryAxis.normalized);
        player2.transform.position = symmetryPoint + v2;
    }
}
```

Edit:

Symmetrical velocity instead of position:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2 symmetryAxis = new Vector2(1, 1);
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Rigidbody2D rb2;
    private Vector2 movement = Vector2.zero;
    void Update()
    {
        movement = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")).normalized;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        var v1 = movement * moveSpeed;
        var v2 = Vector2.Reflect(-v1, symmetryAxis.normalized);
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + v1);
        rb2.MovePosition(rb2.position + v2);
    }
}
```

There are two problems with the previous code:

1. You should use the normalized value of the moving direction, otherwise the speed will become sqrt(2) when walking diagonally.
2. You should not use `Time.fixedDeltaTime` inside `FixedUpdate()`, it will be used automatically.

Comment: How would I maintain my collisions? If for example the player1 hits a wall but the player hold down the left key, I want player 2 to keep moving. And when player2 hits a wall, I want it to stop because right now player 2 will go through the collisions on the tile map

Comment: Added an editor, only the movement speed is symmetrical at this time, and their collisions will be handled separately by themselves. Also, there are some small problem that need to be pointed out. holp it helps : )